# Why the first stop at a Delphi breakpoint takes a lot of time

Tags: windows, debugging, delphi

If I debug a hughe project then the first stop at a breakpoint takes a lot of time. The next stops then are fast. I use Delphi 10.4, but this also occurs with Delphi 12. The time after first stop is 1 to 3 minutes (machine: intel i7, 20 cores, 64GB, Rtx3060). What can I do against it?

Open hughe project, set a breakpoint, run with debugger till breakpoint, then the program stops and switch to the Delphi IDE. But I can not continues my work for minutes. After the first stop all works fine.

@Brian: that was a good tip. I have investigated this. The only operation that the bds.exe does for 2 min is that it reads a lot of small blocks from the compiled exe:

```
15:31:19,1997607    bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
248.425.414, Length: 107 15:31:19,1997655   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
249.906.298, Length: 107 15:31:19,1997703   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
251.726.090, Length: 105 15:31:19,1997779   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
255.639.887, Length: 107 15:31:19,1997826   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
257.329.110, Length: 110 15:31:19,1997875   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
258.010.615, Length: 105 15:31:19,1997950   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
258.207.089, Length: 107 15:31:19,1997996   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
261.965.132, Length: 107 15:31:19,1998043   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
262.108.471, Length: 108 15:31:19,1998088   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
262.662.311, Length: 107 15:31:19,1998136   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
269.833.899, Length: 105 15:31:19,1998184   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
272.001.115, Length: 107 15:31:19,1998242   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
275.428.078, Length: 108 15:31:19,1998287   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
275.978.400, Length: 107 15:31:19,1998409   bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
239.579.809, Length: 8 15:31:19,1998460 bds.exe 10872   ReadFile    E:\Delphi\GEOvision.Win32\Kernel\GEOvision.exe  SUCCESS Offset:
251.614.721, Length: 105
```

Comment: A guess for that extreme a time: looking for symbols to load from no longer existing network locations. Suggest using something to monitor what it is doing during that time - Sysinternals Process Monitor is one way to do that (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have find out the reason of the problem: I have linked debug infos to the host application (project options/ linker/ debuginfos). If I disable this all is fine. If not then collect the bde all infos from the exe what consumes a long time.
Thanks.